# Shopify Storefron API - Search query containing term not working

Tags: search, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

so what i want to do is querying the products title with a search term and i expect to get all products containing the term somewhere in the title to be returned.

For example in the graphql explorer we have this product title: "3/4 SLEEVE CREWNECK PULLOVER"

I want this to be returned with the following query:

```js
{
  products(first: 250, query:"title:neck") {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the docs i can't figure out a way. If you want to try it out you can do it here: https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/tools/graphiql-storefront-api

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the query like that will match only product with the same exact title. To search any title containing the string add `*`:

```
{
  products(first: 250, query:"title:neck*") {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabio

The problem with this is, that i won't get "3/4 SLEEVE CREWNECK PULLOVER", but "neck" is contained in the title.

Any further hint appreciated!

Comment: @DanielRoth I'm afraid you can't do that. You can't use regexp or search inside words. In the title or any other field. https://shopify.dev/api/usage/search-syntax#prefix-query